# When using x as index no. to show array location in a funtion, the array returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Hi guys so my function is returning undefined when I am using x to represent the index number of an array in the below code, why is this happening?
It would be very much appreciated if somebody could answer my question
Code:

```js
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var z = 0;
var x = 0;
function findOutlier(integers){
  //your code here
while(x < integers.length){
    if(integers[x]%2 === 0){
      a = x;
      z = z + 1;
    }
   else{
    b = x;
   }
      x = x + 1
   
}
if(z === 1){return integers[a]}
else{return integers[b]}
 
}
findOutlier([2,6,8,10,3]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x <= integers.length`  The array goes from 0 to length-1, so looping from 0 to length means you are going one off the end of the array.

Replace with `while(x < integers.length)`.

Comment: Mate that was wrong and I just noticed
Thanks for pointing it out
But that still didn't solve my ACTUAL problem
when placing code: integers[x] in the function, the function returns undefined every time, instead if I place a random number for the index ex: integers[1]
the function responds correctly
why is that?
help me out a bit here :/